# What does @ mean in path of import?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

What does the `@` mean in this import ?

```
import NotFound from '@/components/404'
```

It's located in router/index.js on this folder:

```
 |-src
   |--assets
   |--components
      |-- 404.vue
   |--router
      |-- index.js
   |-- App.vue
   |-- main.js
```

Comment: Reading material [`The @ symbol in JavaScript import statement`](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/til-at-symbol-javascript-import/)

Comment: @ is the src folder of your project. So when ever you give @ in path, it will take src folder.